# Options Explicit, worksheet change event, Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA, but I have some minor code expirence from Matlab and C++.

I have written the following code intended to display a msgbox-message if a certain cell is changed to contain a certain text string from a drop-down list:

```
Options Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then
        If Range("C7").Value = "Blue home" Then
        MsgBox "Hello world!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I get the following error message: Compile error: Invalid outside procedure

When I remove options explicit from the code and turn off the require variable declaration options under tools in the VBE, the code works. Thus the options explicit line triggers the problem.

What is causing problems with options explicit? I cannot really figure out that there are any variables in my code that needs to be declared.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is `Option Explicit` not `Options Explicit`.

Comment: for your further coding, should your `Worksheet_Change()` sub need to edit any cell of the same worksheet then place `Application.EnableEvents = False` right after `If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then` statement and `Application.EnableEvents = True` right before its corresponding `End If`

Comment: Is the code in a normal code module?  It belongs in a worksheet code module.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. That sounds like a good habbit user3598756. The code is placed in a worksheet code module.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Jeeped is correct in his comment you spelled it wrong it should look like below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then
        If Range("C7").Value = "Blue home" Then
        MsgBox "Hello world!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```